# To associate argument with process name in python

Tags: python

The below script creates a process with name "python test_script.py".

```
import os
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "test_script.py", "a"], shell=False)
```

Is there a way to create a process with name as "python test_script.py -n 1234" through Python.

Comment: on which OS? linux? windows? on windows the process name is "python.exe" no matter what, but tools like ProcessMonitor are able to print the arguments.

Comment: It's in Unix...

Comment: you mean that `ps -ef` gives that output then. But the process name is still `python`

Comment: Yes. I want ps -ef to return 'python test_script.py -n 1234'

Comment: have you tried `ps -ef -o args=` ?

Comment: That doesnt return any useful information